# calling a c function in another class

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i am having objective c class, which i have a C function in it.
in that C function i want to call to ANOTHER c function in another class.

in the first class C function , i do this :

```
  HelloWorldLayer *ran;
  ran=[[HelloWorldLayer alloc] init];
  [ran showDigital:BinaryWord];
```

when `HelloWorldLayer` is the other class, which have the C function :

`void showDigital( int word[4])`

and it declared also in the `HelloWorldLayer.h` .

in the first class, when i am trying to call the other function it says that showDigital function is not found.

is it has to do with the fact that its a C function ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the C function is not **in** the other class, it is merely in the same file as the other class.  Objective-C classes have methods not functions.

So you can call your C function from anywhere provided you have an extern declaration of it.  e.g. in `HelloWorldLayer.h`

```
extern void showDigital(int* word);
```

If you really want the function to be associated with instances of your class, you need to make it an Objective-C method.  You can have that method be a thin wrapper for the original function if you like:

```
-(void) showDigital: (int*) word
{
    showDigital(word);
}
```

If you want to pretend that your C function is part of an object, you'll need to add the receiver object as a parameter.  You still won't be able to access private instance variables directly though.

```
void showDigital(id self, int* word)
{
    [self foobar];
}
```

Comment: i cant do it as an objective c function because i need to pass it an array with numbers and i want to do that in c. objective c NSArrays cant get numbers so i need to work with a c function. my Question is: how would i call , a C function, from another class ?

Comment: ok got it . i put the extern and the i call it with showDigital(BinaryWord);  thats works. thanks a lot.

Comment: BUT now i have another problem. lets assume that i HAVE /MUST use the C function. and then when i calculate something there i need to pass it to another objective c method in the same class. how would i do that ? all data in the c function stay there? cant i use C somethimes and pass its data out to an objective c method ?

Comment: @Rant: Objective C methods can take pointers to normal C variables as parameters so you can use the method signature in my example to pass a C array of ints.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to call a C function or an Objective-C method? You've got your terminology all muddled. I think you want to define an Objective-C method on `HelloWorldLayer` and call that, so here is what your header should look like:

HelloWorldLayer.h

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer : NSObject

- (void)sendDigital:(int[4])word;

@end
```

Then you can call that method by doing what you have already tried.

You can't declare a C function inside an Objective-C class. You could define it in your `@interface` block, but it wouldn't be part of that Objective-C class. Only Objective-C methods can be part of the class.

So for instance if you really *really* **really** wanted you could do:

HelloWorldLayer.h

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer : NSObject

void sendDigital(int[4] word);

@end
```

But when you called `sendDigital` you'd have to do it like this:

```
int word[4] = {1,2,3,4};
sendDigital(word);
```

And you'll notice there's no `HelloWorldLayer` around at all. Now do you understand the difference here? I really do think you need to define your method as an Objective-C method rather than a C function.

Comment: NO i cant, and it gives me errors. as i said i am declaring a C function , and C function is with: void, and NOT -(void) .

Comment: But you're calling an Objective-C method. Decide which one you want and stick with it.

Comment: Yes, you're wrong with the concept there. If you want your `sendDigital` to be part of the `HelloWorldLayer` class then it needs to be an Objective-C method.

Comment: thanks for the edit. you right but sometimes C is better. for example, apple , in a very strange way, wouldnt let you put numbers in NSMutuable array and you need to use other NSInteger ways. but a C function, would let me put numbers in my arrays, so thats why i use it. NOW if i do what you have just said and call that c function, then i have another problem that i cant put in it [self addChild] BECAUSE it cant recognize the "self". so i am really running here into some stupid problems and all because the arrays thing.

Comment: You can't put an `int` into an `NSArray`, no. You have to put objects (`id` type) into an `NSArray`. So, just wrap your `int` into an `NSNumber` like so: `NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10]; [mutableArray addObject:number];`